# setBridgeToUseWith() error

Tags: ios, swift, philips-hue

i have the following problem.

Iam trying to set the bridge to use with like this:

```
self.hue.setBridgeToUseWithId(mac, ipAddress: ip)
```

But every time i try this i get this error:

> username could not be read for bridge id: 001788FFFE709507, so try to load the generic username for all bridges

and this:

> generic username could not be loaded, so try to load unique device identifier:

Thank`s for your help.

Note: I am using Swift

Comment: I don't know what this will do, but maybe try replacing self with the name or id or even its ip?